# Slice of a struct's field to variadic

Tags: go, struct, slice, variadic

My application has a slice of a struct like so

```
type ItemOrder struct {
    ItemId
    ...
}

var items = []*ItemOrder
```

And a variadic function accepting `...int`

```
func ItemIds(lang string, ids ...int){
...
```

How can I take all itemIds from the `items []*ItemOrder` slice and supply it to the variadic function? Something like

```
itemsPB, err := ItemIds("", items[:].itemId)
```

Abov doesnt work because im not giving  the slice a position to extract itemId from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a new slice for the IDs, and use a loop to populate it. There is no shortcut.

For example:

```
ids := make([]int, len(items))
for i, item := range items {
    ids[i] = item.ItemId
}
ItemIds("en", ids...)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/V2aN55hHBj8).

Comment: @krijn-van-der-burg, note that one of the design goals of Go is to have (almost) no magic. If you'll think about your proposed idea a bit harder, you'll notice that to achieve what you imagine the Go compiler would have allocate a memory for a special slice the length of `len(items)*sizeof(int)`, fill it up with the IDs and then pass to the function; and that price whould have been paid on each call to that function. Now imagine you have 1bn items in your slice. So no, Go forces you to not hide such things behind innocently-looking expressions.

Comment: Didnt know / think about that Kostix, thanks for the addition. Makes me feel better about applying "yet another loop" as its inevitable in my case.